# Keyboard overlapping Textfield iphone 4 / 4s monotouch

Tags: c#, coding-style, xamarin.ios, textfield

So in my app the keyboard is overlapping the textfield on an iPhone 4 / 4s. To fix this I could just check for the device and move every thing up by changing the position. Although this should work I have the strong feeling there is an easier / better way to do this.

[image]
[image]

any ideas?

Comment: See native solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present

Comment: Lets see how far I can get with this. I would prefer a c# / monotouch solution though.

Comment: Yep: http://spazzarama.com/2011/09/07/monotouch-auto-scroll-uitextfield-or-other-views-hidden-by-keyboard/

Comment: Simpliest solution is convert `UIViewController` into `UITableViewController` and place `UITextField`s into it's `TableView` cells.

Comment: @MaximKorobov Looks solid, Thanks gonna try this.

Comment: you can solve it too with a behavior http://blog.reblochon.org/2013/04/decorating-your-xamarinios-code-with.html

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix Not realy sure how to implement this after reading the blog post. Do i have to make a new SlideOnEditBehavior class? If so what reference are you using im missing the reference for Behavior.

Comment: there's no Behavior avail in touch, but you can implement it, it's quick. All the code is on github